# MySQLi query in PHP isn't working right, is there a way to get the exact query?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way to get the query after [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) prepares it? My query is messing up:

```
$query = "UPDATE event SET group=?, boxed=?, name=?, location=?, time=?, day=?, type=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
{
    $stmt -> bind_param("iisssssi", $group, $boxed, $name, $location, $time, $day, $etype, $id);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
}
else
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group=?, boxed=?, name=?, location=?, time=?, day=?, type=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1' at line 1

Variable `group` is an int, `boxed` is an int, the rest are strings, and `id` is an int.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the SQL reserved word "group" as one of the column names.

Comment: and you can fix this by using `` around the column name.  That's the character left of 1 on a querty keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get the query after MySQLi prepares it, because there is no query in the usual sense. The string goes to the server as you wrote it - with question marks. That's an annoying disadvantage of the prepared statements.